# Splitting a single column data to multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

**MS SQL Server:**

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Coltable
(
    Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Coltable
VALUES
('P'),
('Q'),
('R'),
('S'),
('T'),
('U'),
('V'),
('W'),
('X')
```

want the result as below:

```
col1 col2  col3

P     Q     R
S     T     U
V     W     X
```

First record (P) has to be inserted into first row column number 1 (Col1),
Second row (Q) has to be inserted into second column (COL2),
Third row (R) has to be inserted into third column (col3),
Fourth row (S) has to be inserted into first column (col1) as next row,
Fifth row (T) has to be inserted into second column (col2) as next row and like this it contiues.

Comment: You need an explicit order for this (from a column) as there is no innate ordering of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your row ordering in the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER` of the `ROW_NUMBER()` to correctly order the records before pivoting.

```
WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Name,
        Ordering = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
        #Coltable AS C
),
PrePivot AS
(
    SELECT
        D.Name,
        RowGroup = (D.Ordering - 1) / 3,
        ColumnPosition = 'col' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ((D.Ordering - 1) % 3) + 1)
    FROM
        Data AS D
)
SELECT
    P.col1,
    P.col2,
    P.col3
FROM
    PrePivot AS V
    PIVOT (
        MAX(V.Name) FOR ColumnPosition IN ([col1], [col2], [col3])
    ) AS P
```

This solution calculates an ascending integer ranking for each of your rows, then using division (`/`) by 3 we can group each set together and using mod (`%`) by 3 we can know which column the value will end up with. Finally pivot the value throughout the group counter (but don't display the group counter!).

Comment: Thanking you i think most of the cases can be achieved by using cte and i'm not good at cte